# I need assistance with an Angular/Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

So, I'm just learning how to do Angular and I'm also doing it with Ionic.  I'm trying to make the first page of my cordova app using visual studio.  I've already discovered a bunch of errors in my code that I have already fixed, but there has to be more because it still doesn't work like it should.  All help will be appreciated.  Here is part of the code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.darkness = darkness;
    darkness = "Darkness"

    $scope.myFunction = function () {
        $scope.text = text;
        text = "Nothing but darkness and the pain that radiates through your very being."

    }
});
```

```html
<body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">      
            <p> {{ darkness }} </p>
            <p>  {{ text }} </p>
            <button ng-click="myFunction()">???</button>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>        
        <script src="scripts/gamefunctions/chapterone.js"></script><script src="scripts/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Add AngularJS**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>    
  <script src="scripts/gamefunctions/chapterone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
```

**Define 1st then use it**

```
var    darkness = "Darkness";
$scope.darkness = darkness;

var text = "Nothing but darkness and the pain that radiates through your very being.";        
$scope.text = text;
```

Comment: don't forget semicolon after text declaration.

Comment: I'm also using the ionic.bundle script so that includes the angular js along with the ionic.

Comment: <script src="scripts/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

That's the script I have for ionic and it includes the angular.  For security reasons for putting it on with app store, I can't have scripts with links in them.

Comment: try using cdn's instead of local copies of ionic.bundle.js and wat error are you getting ??

Comment: What are cdns?  Also, with the previous version of my app where I just used jquery.mobile, I used local scripts and it worked so I know that's not the problem.  And the error I'm getting is when I run the emulation of my app I get this:

{{ text }}

{{ darkness }}

And the button I put in which doesn't work.

Comment: i think the problem is the order in which your are loading your js files check the latest edit of my ans

Comment: Okay then, I'll try and rearrange the scripts then.  Thank you.

Comment: That actually solved my problem thank you so much!  I was just having so many errors inside the code itself, I thought that was the problem lol.

Comment: @Chiarra Glad I Could Help :)

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is you declared darkness after you assigned it to $scope.

So it should be :

```
var darkness = "Darkness";
$scope.darkness = darkness;
```

Also text should be defined like the following:

```
 var text = "Nothing but darkness and the pain that radiates through your very being.";
 $scope.text = text;
```

Comment: Same thing with text

Comment: So, I added the var code as you said and semicolons, but that still doesn't fix it.  I also moved the var above the $scope.

Comment: @Chiarra Did you include the angularjs file? It says that angular is not defined

Comment: I have all the scripts I need.  I'm using the Ionic.bundle script and that has the angular included.

Comment: I didn't add the rest of the code that was building the cordova app, just the actual code I added in and needed help fixing.